# Managing log file size

Tags: c, file, logging

I have a program which logs its activity.
I want to implement a log file mechanism to keep the log file under a certain size, lets say 10 MB.
The log file itself just holds commands the program executed; those commands are variable length.

Right now, the program runs on a windows environment, but I'm likely to port it to UNIX soon.

### **I've came up with two methods for managing the log files:**

**1.** Keep multiple files of lower size, and if the new command exceeds the current file length, truncate the oldest file to zero size, and start writing there.

**2.** Keep a header in the file, which holds metadata regarding the first command in the file, and the next place to write to in the file. *Also I think, each command should hold metadata about it's length this way.*

**My questions are as follows:**

- In terms of efficiency which of these methods would you use, and why?
- Is there a unix command / function to this easily?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Nihil.

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX/Linux platforms there's a logrotate program that manages logfiles. Details can be found for example here:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Comment: And how would I call such a program from C code?
So this is basically a program that manages log files like the first method I mentioned, right?

Comment: You can launch it from your application using sytem(...) function but usually it's called as crob job. You will also need to create state file and configuration file or modify the deafault one (/var/lib/logrotate.status and /etc/logrotate.conf) to specify rules for your logs. Basically yes, but it also has more advanced features (compressing, mailing).